# Как сделать фоновую работу приложения в react-native+expo?

Tags: react-native, background, background-task, expo

вообщем нужно чтобы приложение работало в фоне при выключенном экране, свернутом приложении и запускала определение местоположения раз в секунду.
использую react-native + expo 35
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

- https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/sdk/location/
- https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/sdk/task-manager/#configuration-for-standalone-apps

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

const LOCATION_TASK_NAME = 'background-location-task';

export default class Component extends React.Component {
  onPress = async () => {
    await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, {
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Balanced,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPress}>
        <Text>Enable background location</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, ({ data, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    // Error occurred - check `error.message` for more details.
    return;
  }
  if (data) {
    const { locations } = data;
    // do something with the locations captured in the background
  }
});
```

Comment: эта штука работает если дисплей влкючен. в приостановленном режиме не работает(выключенный экран)

Comment: прочитай про task-manager https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/sdk/task-manager/#configuration-for-standalone-apps включен ли UIBackgroundModes если это ios

Comment: добавил параметр distanceInterval: 0 теперь координаты получаются но теперь звук в фоне не работает.

Comment: Эта функция находится в разработке https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/audio-playback-in-background

Comment: staysActiveInBackground вот этот параметр вроде для бэкгроунда. есть пример как использовать